# Push div below down to bottom of page and adapt on page resize

Tags: html, css

I have a sidebar and in this sidebar I have two divs. Div1 is on top of Div2. I want Div2 to be at the bottom of the sidebar but when the page is small enough Div2 will not cover Div1.

[image]

Has soon as page shrinks and Div2 starts to take Div1 space, Div1 will show the scrollbar (overflow: auto).

Div2 should be at the bottom of the page and not cliping after the page size

Comment: Consider if the relative `vh` units are useful in this case, in combination with media queries.

Comment: use css `flex` property

Comment: @simon, can you provide some details for my case? flex on what element?

Comment: like myStream told use media queries: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp  and `vh` (viewport height) and `vw` (viewport width).